# Java - Connecting a client to a server without the localhost

Tags: java

Hello world, I made an instant messenger with the server and the client that runs on a localhost, but I want to put the client on another computer but it cannot connect to the server without the localhost, please can I get some help(codes) that i can use to connect the client on another computer to the server on my own computer without the use of a localhost.

Comment: Please, paste here some code.

Comment: WHat do you mean, "cannot connect?"  Are you getting an error?  If so,please detail it. We are not mind readers.

Comment: Can't you use IP address  of the server to connect your client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ipconfig
```

command on Windows (in command-line) to get your IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Get the Ip Address of the server machine, and replace the "localhost" in the client code with the Server IP.